# How to properly use Wire.onReceive in Arduino

Tags: arduino

I've got a stream of messages coming into an I2C slave from its master.

How do I properly resolve the below issues?

If I do:

```
Wire.onReceive(handler);

void handler(int howMany) {
    byte message = Wire.read();
}
```

What should I do with `message`? I shouldn't process it in the ISR in order to keep the interrupt slim and fast. If I instead do:

```
volatile byte message;
```

and then set this from the ISR and read it inside `loop()`, I might not loop fast enough to read quickly incoming messages - thus losing messages.

So instead I can create a buffer, and push to it from inside the ISR, and then read from `loop()` but that's even more susceptible to race conditions - unless I disable interrupts whilst I take a local copy of the buffer - but with interrupts off I'll miss messages.

Wire has an internal rx buffer, so I'd have thought I could just call `Wire.available()` and `Wire.read()` from inside my `loop`, but the implementation of Wire.cpp states:

```
// must be called in:
// slave rx event callback
// or after requestFrom(address, numBytes)
int TwoWire::available(void);
```

So, what's the right way to do this? How do I handle/enqueue fast incoming i2c messages and process them all without dropping data?

Assume I can process messages faster than my rx buffer will fill up, messages will just come in bursts, so no need to care about overflows necessarily.

Comment: The `Wire.onReceive(handler);` itself setup an ISR internally behind the scene. So you don't need to setup another ISR. When it is triggered, the callback function get called, if you want to use a buffer , just declare a buffer as a global `volatile byte buf [32];`, and it is okay to read the data in, based on the `howMany` bytes are available, `for (byte i = 0; i < howMany; i++)  buf [i] = Wire.read ();` but if you need to further process it, set a flog and do it outside the handler().

Comment: For wire library, maximum of 32 bytes can be sent by the master, therefore the maximum you could received at the handler would be 32 bytes before next batch of data arrive...